# What means "reduce performance by 1.5% at 10e-4 FPPW"?

Tags: computer-vision

When I read paper [Histograms of Oriented Gradients for Human Detection](http://people.csail.mit.edu/torralba/courses/6.870/papers/hog_cvpr2005.pdf), some problems beats me.

I know what **FPPW** means (False Positives Per Window,the number of negative samples : **N**, the number of the exmaple which the classifier recognize negative sample as positive sample : **FP**, So **FPPW = FP / N**).

But What means "reduce performance by 1.5% at 10e-4 FPPW"? I'm not a English native speaker, I can understand "reduce performance by 1.5%". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the paper you mention, performance plots show *miss rate* vs. *FPPW*. Performance (*miss rate*) depends on which point in the curve you consider, and so does the reduction in performance due to the different ideas they test.

The "*at 10e-4 FPPW*" part specifies which point of the curve they are talking about, as the reduction in performance can be different for other values of FPPW.

Comment: Thank you~ So I have a new comprehension：The figure in the paper show the curve, x axis :FPPW, the smaller FFPW is，the smaller of miss rate of  the method author proposed . We use hard example (the negative example that are recognized as positive example) to train model again and again using HOG, so the FFPW will be smaller and smaller. On the other hand, the HoG-based method is better than other method in low FFPW (10e-6,10e-5,10e-4) obviously, but they are no obvious difference in high FFPW (10e-3,10e-2，10e-1)。